# CSP (Content-Security-Policy) Violation stats.g.doubleclick.net in spite of hostname added to list

Tags: content-security-policy

I am trying to add CSP to our web site, using report-only (to report-uri.com).
It seems to work as expected for most cases, but google related sites gets reported even if the URL is added to the header.

Here´s the relevant part of header as it appears in developer tools:
connect-src 'self' https://stats.g.doubleclick.net

I am still getting this violation:
"blocked-uri": "https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/j/collect"

I have experienced similar issues with other Google related sites as well.

The problem is that we're using Google tags and analysis, so I cannot block the sites out.

This particular problem seems to come from Chrome only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to `blocked-uri`, note in the reports on the `original-policy` field - is there your CSP with the `connect-src 'self' https://stats.g.doubleclick.net` rule or not.

Looks like some ISPs, in violation of RFCs, cache site responses along with HTTP headers. At least after the changes in the CSP, within 2 weeks there is violation reports having the old CSP in the `original-policy` field.
And it feels like you changed the rules in `connect-src` directive recently.

> 

List of sources `connect-src 'self' https://stats.g.doubleclick.net` is [not complete](https://csplite.com/csp/test31/) for Google Analytics, you can insert own Google Analytics ID and check. [Here](https://csplite.com/csp/test141/) is comprehensive test of Content Security Policy for GTM.

Here is initial CSP for [GA + GTM](https://csplite.com/csp/svc/?pl=eJxNjt0KwjAMhd8l90I359DTd%2FAdQlsh0LXQFkXG3t2GCnqV5OP8hHHFXrGCHhJbKGQrDEjHDBJPlvuyC9ZBciIrmMztdx4VF1DKyQWy986nBVRbEddO%2Fp14Ezd4V8XwDFETZtX1opdE77j4ev56%2F9kymD6Xy8ZNjcYeH8MlNkU%3D#CSP_rules). The initial because though GTM you can embed a lot of third-party scripts from vary sources.

Comment: Please include samples in answer. Linked content requires some kind of payment or  account...